# What is the random portion of the FQDN assigned to a container group deployed through the Azure portal?

Tags: azure, containers

When I deploy an instance through the portal, the structure of the FQDN my container is assigned is:

```
{domain label}.{seemingly random string}.{region}.azurecontainer.io
```

Deleting & redeploying an identical instance yields the same random string portion, so at least it's not randomized for each deployment, but as this does not conform to the structure defined [here in the Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart-portal), I'm left without any explanation.  Is it a hash?  An id?  How can this be predicted before deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is related to [Prevent dangling DNS entries and avoid subdomain takeover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/security/fundamentals/subdomain-takeover) and [ACI DNS name reuse policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/how-to-reuse-dns-names):

> In order to avoid this, ACI will now allow customers to reuse DNS
> names while preventing DNS names from being reused by different
> customers. ACI secures DNS names by randomly generating a hash value
> to associate with the DNS name, making it difficult for another
> customer to accidentally create an ACI with the same name and get
> linked to the past customer's ACI information.

There are five "reuse levels" that use hashing to generate a unique DNS name for your container group:

- `noReuse` - no hash, object's DNS name cannot be reused.
- `unsecure` - hash is based on the DNS name only (aka Any Reuse).
- `tenantReuse` **(default)** - hash is based on the DNS name and Tenant ID.
- `subscriptionReuse` - hash is based on the DNS name, the tenant ID and subscription ID.
- `resourceGroupReuse` - hash is based on the DNS name, the tenant ID, subscription ID and resource group name.